# plot fibonacci on MA Cross

Tags: pine-script

Hi I want to plot a fibonacci once everytime two MA cross (50,200)
but i cant figure it out tried an array that didnt work either or maybe my array was wrong
does anyone know how ?

```
extendType  =input(false, title="Extend Lines?") ? extend.right : extend.none
show_price  =input(true, title="Show Prices?")
FPeriod= input(100, title="Lookback Length before MA Cross")
Fhigh =highest(FPeriod)
Flow = lowest(FPeriod)
SwingHigh=highestbars(high,FPeriod)
SwingLow = lowestbars(low,FPeriod)
downfib = Fhigh < Flow

X1_offset = downfib ? Fhigh : Flow
X2_offset = 5

bar_index_duration = time - time[1] // time between bars

X1 = X1_offset * bar_index_duration //Starting level X position
X2 = X2_offset * bar_index_duration //Ending level X position
lbl_X2 = ((show_price ? 15:6) + X2_offset) * bar_index_duration // label X position


FN061 = downfib ? (Fhigh - Flow) * -0.618 + Flow : Fhigh - (Fhigh - Flow) * -0.618 //
FN027 = downfib ? (Fhigh - Flow) * -0.27 + Flow : Fhigh - (Fhigh - Flow) * -0.27 //
F000 = downfib ? Flow : Fhigh
F382 = downfib ? (Fhigh - Flow) * 0.382  + Flow : Fhigh - (Fhigh - Flow) * 0.382
F500 = downfib ? (Fhigh - Flow) *0.500  + Flow : Fhigh - (Fhigh - Flow) * 0.500
F618 = downfib ? (Fhigh - Flow) *0.618  + Flow : Fhigh - (Fhigh - Flow) *0.618
F716 = downfib ? (Fhigh - Flow) *0.716  + Flow : Fhigh - (Fhigh - Flow) *0.716
F786 = downfib ? (Fhigh - Flow) *0.786  + Flow : Fhigh - (Fhigh - Flow) *0.786 //
F886 = downfib ? (Fhigh - Flow) * 0.886 + Flow : Fhigh - (Fhigh - Flow) * 0.886 //
F100 = downfib ? Fhigh : Flow
F113 = downfib ? (Fhigh - Flow) * 1.13 + Flow : Fhigh - (Fhigh - Flow) * 1.13 //

LevelColor = input(color.black, " Fib Level Color", type = input.color)
StopColor  = input(color.red, "Stop Levels Color", type = input.color)
F618_color = color.new(#458B00,0)

FN061_lbl = show_price ? "-61% [" + tostring(FN061) + " ]" : "-61%"
FN027_lbl = show_price ? "-27% [" + tostring(FN027) + " ]" : "-27%"
F000_lbl = show_price ? "0% [" + tostring(F000) + " ]" : "0%"
F382_lbl = show_price ? "38.2% [" + tostring(F382) + " ]" : "38.2%"
F500_lbl = show_price ? "50% [" + tostring(F500) + " ]" : "50.0%"
F618_lbl = show_price ? "61.8% [" + tostring(F618) + " ]" : "61,8%"
F716_lbl = show_price ? "71.6% [" + tostring(F716) + " ]" : "71.6%"
F786_lbl = show_price ? "786% [" + tostring(F786) + " ]" : "78.6%"
F886_lbl = show_price ? "88.6% [" + tostring(F886) + " ]" : "88.6%"
F100_lbl = show_price ? "100% [" + tostring(F100) + " ]" : "100%"
F113_lbl = show_price ? "113% [" + tostring(F000) + " ]" : "113%"

// Setup Line & Label Appearence 
line_style = line.style_solid
label_style = label.style_none
label_size = size.normal
// -61 line
if true 
    ln = line.new(
     x1 = time + X1, 
     y1 = FN061,
     x2 = time + X2,
     y2 = FN061,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     extend = extendType,
     color = LevelColor,
     style = line_style,
     width = 1
     )
    line.delete(ln[1])

if true
    lbl = label.new(
     x = time + lbl_X2,
     y = FN061, 
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     yloc = yloc.price,
     text = FN061_lbl,
     color = LevelColor,
     textcolor = LevelColor,
     style = label_style, 
     size = label_size
     )
    label.delete(lbl[1])
// -27 line
if true 
    ln = line.new(
     x1 = time + X1, 
     y1 = FN027,
     x2 = time + X2,
     y2 = FN027,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     extend = extendType,
     color = LevelColor,
     style = line_style,
     width = 1
     )
    line.delete(ln[1])

if true
    lbl = label.new(
     x = time + lbl_X2,
     y = FN027, 
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     yloc = yloc.price,
     text = FN027_lbl,
     color = LevelColor,
     textcolor = LevelColor,
     style = label_style, 
     size = label_size
     )
    label.delete(lbl[1])
// 0 line
if true 
    ln = line.new(
     x1 = time + X1, 
     y1 = F000,
     x2 = time + X2,
     y2 = F000,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     extend = extendType,
     color = LevelColor,
     style = line_style,
     width = 1
     )
    line.delete(ln[1])

if true
    lbl = label.new(
     x = time + lbl_X2,
     y = F000, 
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     yloc = yloc.price,
     text = F000_lbl,
     color = LevelColor,
     textcolor = LevelColor,
     style = label_style, 
     size = label_size
     )
    label.delete(lbl[1])
//382
if true 
    ln = line.new(
     x1 = time + X1, 
     y1 = F382,
     x2 = time + X2,
     y2 = F382,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     extend = extendType,
     color = LevelColor,
     style = line_style,
     width = 1
     )
    line.delete(ln[1])

if true
    lbl = label.new(
     x = time + lbl_X2,
     y = F382, 
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     yloc = yloc.price,
     text = F382_lbl,
     color = LevelColor,
     textcolor = LevelColor,
     style = label_style, 
     size = label_size
     )
    label.delete(lbl[1])
//500
if true 
    ln = line.new(
     x1 = time + X1, 
     y1 = F500,
     x2 = time + X2,
     y2 = F500,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     extend = extendType,
     color = LevelColor,
     style = line_style,
     width = 1
     )
    line.delete(ln[1])

if true
    lbl = label.new(
     x = time + lbl_X2,
     y = F500, 
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     yloc = yloc.price,
     text = F500_lbl,
     color = LevelColor,
     textcolor = LevelColor,
     style = label_style, 
     size = label_size
     )
    label.delete(lbl[1])
//618

if true 
    ln = line.new(
     x1 = time + X1, 
     y1 = F618,
     x2 = time + X2,
     y2 = F618,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     extend = extendType,
     color = F618_color,
     style = line_style,
     width = 1
     )
    line.delete(ln[1])

if true
    lbl = label.new(
     x = time + lbl_X2,
     y = F618, 
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     yloc = yloc.price,
     text = F618_lbl,
     color = F618_color,
     textcolor = F618_color,
     style = label_style, 
     size = label_size
     )
    label.delete(lbl[1])
// 71.6 line
if true 
    ln = line.new(
     x1 = time + X1, 
     y1 = F716,
     x2 = time + X2,
     y2 = F716,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     extend = extendType,
     color = LevelColor,
     style = line_style,
     width = 1
     )
    line.delete(ln[1])

if true
    lbl = label.new(
     x = time + lbl_X2,
     y = F716, 
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     yloc = yloc.price,
     text = F716_lbl,
     color = LevelColor,
     textcolor = LevelColor,
     style = label_style, 
     size = label_size
     )
    label.delete(lbl[1])

//786
if true 
    ln = line.new(
     x1 = time + X1, 
     y1 = F786,
     x2 = time + X2,
     y2 = F786,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     extend = extendType,
     color = LevelColor,
     style = line_style,
     width = 1
     )
    line.delete(ln[1])

if true
    lbl = label.new(
     x = time + lbl_X2,
     y = F786, 
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     yloc = yloc.price,
     text = F786_lbl,
     color = LevelColor,
     textcolor = LevelColor,
     style = label_style, 
     size = label_size
     )
    label.delete(lbl[1])
// 886 line
if true 
    ln = line.new(
     x1 = time + X1, 
     y1 = F886,
     x2 = time + X2,
     y2 = F886,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     extend = extendType,
     color = StopColor,
     style = line_style,
     width = 1
     )
    line.delete(ln[1])

if true
    lbl = label.new(
     x = time + lbl_X2,
     y = F886, 
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     yloc = yloc.price,
     text = F886_lbl,
     color = StopColor,
     textcolor = StopColor,
     style = label_style, 
     size = label_size
     )
    label.delete(lbl[1])
// 100
if true 
    ln = line.new(
     x1 = time + X1, 
     y1 = F100,
     x2 = time + X2,
     y2 = F100,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     extend = extendType,
     color = LevelColor,
     style = line_style,
     width = 1
     )
    line.delete(ln[1])

if true
    lbl = label.new(
     x = time + lbl_X2,
     y = F100, 
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     yloc = yloc.price,
     text = F100_lbl,
     color = LevelColor,
     textcolor = LevelColor,
     style = label_style, 
     size = label_size
     )
    label.delete(lbl[1])
// 113 line
if true 
    ln = line.new(
     x1 = time + X1, 
     y1 = F113,
     x2 = time + X2,
     y2 = F113,
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     extend = extendType,
     color = StopColor,
     style = line_style,
     width = 1
     )
    line.delete(ln[1])

if true
    lbl = label.new(
     x = time + lbl_X2,
     y = F113, 
     xloc = xloc.bar_time,
     yloc = yloc.price,
     text = F113_lbl,
     color = StopColor,
     textcolor = StopColor,
     style = label_style, 
     size = label_size
     )
    label.delete(lbl[1])
```

Comment: You know, there is a reason that you have a minimum character requirement. Simply filling your post with junk doesn't help anyone...

Comment: theres more then enough suffecient info

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out was very easy

created this conditions

`MaTime = if MaCross==true

```
time_close `
```

and added them to the x line/label